# Is web socket supported in .NET Core ? throwing "System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException exception

Tags: c#, azure, websocket, .net-core, azure-iot-hub

I have written console application using `.NET Core 2.1`.

The responsibility of this application is: Connect to the `Azure IoT hub` and send data.

I am still getting below exception

> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
>      at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal

**Note**:

- I am running my code on **Windows Embedded Standard.**
- Using web sockets
- Works fine in Windows 10

Here is my nuget references

```
   using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
   using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared;
```

This is how I create connection.

```
   string deviceConnectionString = "*******";
  _Client = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, TransportType.Mqtt_WebSocket_Only);
```

**web sockets will not work on windows 7**. Reference: [Using WebSocket on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039438/using-websocket-on-windows-7)

So I am using .NET Core 2.1 to get web socket support, as mentioned here https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20191

Still I get the same error!

what does below means?

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation?

**Update**

It seems the .NET runtime is not able to call the older Windows Embedded Standard APIs to validate the certificate for TLS. I may need to do that within mycode itself.

Some details are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support

The other option is to compile the C SDK, which already has this certificate for TLS. It can be called through our C# code. It will be compact and less dependency.

Comment: Might be missing some root certificate which make the certificate encrypting the wss connection invalid.

Comment: is it possible to skip certificate verification?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have a high enough rep to comment I'll provide this as an answer though it is more of a suggestion. I ran into a similar problem and needed to connect to an IoT hub from Windows Embedded. I didn't get as far as you since I also needed to use a web proxy and there was no way to do that with the C# SDK and .Net Core.

I went in the second direction that you mentioned and compiled the C SDK. Since my client did not have C experience, I built a C# P/Invoke wrapper around the C SDK dlls. Perhaps it will be of some use to you. You can find it here: https://github.com/markrad/IoTPInvoke